# When were the minor fast days decreed by the rabbis?

Tags: history, fast-days, derabanan

Five of the six annual fast days are rabbinic and four are "minor" (i.e., daylight fasts).  When, historically, were these five fast days decreed and which is the last to be decreed by the rabbis?

Comment: https://etzion.org.il/en/halakha/orach-chaim/holidays/laws-fasts-status-four-fasts-today

Comment: Yeah I wonder too. Were they fasting for Tisha Bav the year after it was destroyed already

Comment: Zechariah 8:19. But clearly taanit esther is by far the latest

Comment: They fasted for Tish'a b'Av even in the centuries when the 2nd Temple was standing.  That's what the people wanted, over the objections of the rabbis and God through Zechariah:  "[People were asking:] Should I weep... separating myself, as I have done... for ... [the] seventy years [of exile in Babylon]...? [Zech. 7:3-5] ... The Lord of Hosts said as follows: The [four fast days] shall become to the house of Judah days of joy and gladness, and cheerful feasts." [Zech. 8:19]

Comment: @DoubleAA How long is "by far"?